# JVM porting to ARM related (Test plan for Test.java from SUN microsystems.)

Tags: java

Here is ported the JVM into one ARM board. When i run the Test.java from Sun Microsystems , the suite fails at the after Garbagecollector functionality( testSunMiscGC() ).

I didn't have the Test plan of this Test.java (heard it is unavailable ) .

But i dont know java at all and it is not at all easy to grasp  the test well to debug the error related to garbage collector thread.

can some body give the test plan for this Test.java for JVM porting from SUN or any link ?

regards,

/renjith g

---

yes yes . am using phoneMe itself.
when i run the test suite Test.java ported to my board , thrown the following output, sygnal 11 at Garbage collector , when i comment the GC then it would be fine and all the test cases are passed succesfully.

Attaching the output here:

*Number of command line arguments: 0
Starting test1
...recurse
...recurse
...recurse
...recurse
...recurse
...link
...link
...link
Starting test1 again
...recurse
...recurse
...recurse
...recurse
...recurse
...recurse
...recurse
...link
...link
...link
test6: Caught inner java.lang.NullPointerException
test6: Caught outer java.lang.NullPointerException
Testing Array Copy
Testing Float Array Copy

*TestE exception thrown because "I'm feeling Testy"
* threw java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
* threw java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StaticE
c1 = class [LTest;
c2 = class [[LTest;
c3 = class [LC;
c4 = class [[LC;
c1.modifiers = 1041
c2.modifiers = 1041
c3.modifiers = 1040
c4.modifiers = 1040
*FloatMIN =1.4E-45
*FloatMAX =3.4028235E38
FloatMIN (the int bits) =1
FloatMAX (the int bits) =2139095039
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: too many dimensions
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.multiNewArray(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at Test.testDeepArrayConstruction(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.CVM.runMain(Unknown Source)
Constructed an object of type [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[LTest;
finally!
Total memory = 2097152
Free memory = 1965496
Requesting GC with a latency request of 2 seconds
(Turning GC tracing on)
Sleeping 5 seconds, and waiting for GC's
Woke up! Cancelling latency request
Free memory = 2009492
gng to call many fields and methods
 **Process #850 received signal 11, suspending
[1] + Stopped (signal)           ./bin/cvm -Xbootclasspath/p:./cdc_classes -**

I have put some printf's for debugging .

Also , can you please tell me if tehre is any way to debug  these thread of executions in linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [phoneMe](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/), the JVM for embedded devices? The entire [source code and tests](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/downloads_page.html) are available for it from its project page. They have a decent enough [forum](http://forums.java.net/jive/category.jspa?categoryID=56) which some of the project developers seem to be somewhat active on, last time I had problems porting to a different platform they were quite helpful.

Comment: It is not possible for  me to post my doubts in http://forums.java.net/jive/category.jspa?categoryID=56